# Can't bring data into Create Table, says 0 rows processing. Teradata -> The join returns the view but the table won't populate the data

Tags: teradata, create-table

The join returns the view I want but when I go to create the table I get 0 rows processed. I'm sure I'm missing something simple but this is my first time creating tables using queries. Help is appreciated.

THE JOIN:

```
Select 
 a.*,
 b.acct_sk,
 b.voice_estbd_dt,
 b.data_estbd_dt,
 b.video_estbd_dt,
 b.voice_term_dt,
 b.data_term_dt,
 b.video_term_dt,
 b.voice_svc_type_id,
 b.voice_acct_status_id,
 b.data_svc_type_id,
 b.data_acct_status_id,
 b.video_svc_type_id,
 b.video_acct_status_id,
 b.video_svc_type,
 b.data_down_spd_mb,
 b.data_up_spd_mb,
 b.dsl_down_spd_mb,
 b.dsl_up_spd_mb,
 b.fios_down_spd_mb,
 b.fios_up_spd_mb,
 b.prov_speed,
 b.nbr_voice_lines,
 b.tot_trouble_tkts,
 b.trouble_tkts_rslvd,
 b.trouble_tkts_not_rslvd,
 b.tot_truck_rolls,
 b.run_date,
 b.snapshot_dt,
 b.hsi_line_count

from xxx.COVID19_LTRS a

left joinxx.CAR_SERVICE b
ON a.acct_sk = b.acct_sk
AND snapshot_dt = DATE '2020-02-01'
```

THE CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE xxx.aw_smbsuspend_dev_1 as
(Select 
    a.acct_sk,
    a.product_id,
    a.order_save_date,
    a.comments,
    a.b_name,
    a.bill_addr,
    a.bill_city,
    a.bill_state,
    a.bill_zip5,
    a.bill_zip4,
    a.marketing_primary_segment,
    a.ord_creatd_dt,
    b.voice_estbd_dt,
    b.data_estbd_dt,
    b.video_estbd_dt,
    b.voice_svc_type_id,
    b.voice_acct_status_id,
    b.data_svc_type_id,
    b.data_acct_status_id,
    b.video_svc_type_id,
    b.video_acct_status_id,
    b.video_svc_type,
    b.data_down_spd_mb,
    b.data_up_spd_mb,
    b.dsl_down_spd_mb,
    b.dsl_up_spd_mb,
    b.fios_down_spd_mb,
    b.fios_up_spd_mb,
    b.prov_speed,
    b.nbr_voice_lines,
    b.run_date,
    b.snapshot_dt,
    b.hsi_line_count

from xxx.COVID19_LTRS a

left join xx.CAR_SERVICE b
ON a.acct_sk = b.acct_sk
and b.snapshot_dt = DATE '2020-02-01') with data;
```

I have tried adding a group by clause and changing and to where...I am now just adding text because I'm being told to add more explanation but it is a very straightforward problem with a lot of columns.

Comment: Have you queried the table to see if the data is present? Maybe the message is just telling you that `CREATE TABLE AS … WITH DATA` returned nothing to the client, which is what you would expect, and the use of the word "processed" in the text is unfortunate / misleading.

Comment: Yes the data is there otherwise the first query would not have returned results. 'processed' is the wording used by the DB.

Comment: My question was whether the data has been inserted to the **aw_smbsuspend_dev_1** table you are creating. You were clear that the data is in the source tables.

Comment: I didn't...I have used this create query before and it told me a processed number...I should have checked. Thanks!